# UpdatePanel misplaced buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an update panel inside a  tag of a table using the code below. However, because of the update panel, the Log Story button appears on top of the remaining two buttons: reset and cancel. This is probably an easy fix, so how can I align all buttons in one row? Thanks!

```
 <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnSubmit" class="btn" Text="Log Story" runat="server" onClientClick="javascript:return validate();" Width="80px" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="Submit" class="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnReset" class="btn" Text="Reset" onClick="clear" runat="server" Width="70px" />
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnCancel" class="btn" Text="Cancel" onClick="cancel" runat="server" Width="70px" />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<td colspan="2" align="right">
            <table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnSubmit" class="btn" Text="Log Story" runat="server" onClientClick="javascript:return validate();" Width="80px" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="Submit" class="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnReset" class="btn" Text="Reset" onClick="clear" runat="server" Width="70px" />
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button CssClass="button_style" id="btnCancel" class="btn" Text="Cancel" onClick="cancel" runat="server" Width="70px" />
 </td>
```

Comment: @user618616 I edit my previous post. Try to use a nested table instead of placeholder